# Split an array of strings into multiple other arrays within Bash

Tags: arrays, linux, string, bash, split

I have an array `my_array` in Bash that contains string elements formatted as such

```
my_array[0] = "username_1:id_1:name_1"
my_array[1] = "username_2:id_2:name_2"
my_array[2] = "username_3:id_3:name_3"
```

I was curious if there is a convenient way to iterate through this array splitting it on the ":" character and storing the values into three separate arrays. The pseudo-code might look something like this

```
index=0
for i in "${my_array}"
do
   usernames[$index], ids[$index], names[$index]= $(echo $i | tr ":" "\n")
   (( index = index + 1 ))
done
```

This question ([How do I split a string on a delimiter in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/918886/how-do-i-split-a-string-on-a-delimiter-in-bash)) is very similar to what I am trying to accomplish, however I am trying to store the values into three different arrays which is my main obstacle. Thanks in advance for any help as I am extremely new to bash programming.

here is what I have attempted:

```
index=0
for i in "${arrayAdmin[@]}"
do
        credentials=$(echo $i | tr ":" "\n" )

        accounts[$index]=${credentials[0]}
        groups[$index]=${credentials[1]}
        names[$index]=${credentials[2]}
        (( index = $index + 1))
        echo $index
done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `read`, then assign to each array individually.

```
for i in "${my_array[@]}"
do
   IFS=: read -r username id name <<< "$i"
   usernames+=("$username")
   ids+=("$id")
   names+=("$name")
done
```

You could write

```
i=0
for rec in "${my_array[@]}"
do
    IFS=: read -r usernames[i] ids[i] names[i] <<< "$rec"
    ((i++))
done
```

but I find the first loop more readable, in that it doesn't require an explicit loop index for the new arrays.

Or maybe using the same index variable (managed by the `for` loop) for both the input array and the three output arrays.

```
for ((i=0;i < ${#my_array[@]}; i++)); do
    IFS=: read -r usernames[i] ids[i] names[i] <<< "${my_array[i]}"
done
```

And finally, if you don't want to assume the array indices are a continuous sequence and you want to preserve the gaps

```
# For example, my_array=([0]="..." [5]="..." [10]="...")
for i in "${!my_array[@]}"; do
    IFS=: read -r usernames[i] ids[i] names[i] <<< "${my_array[i]}"
done
```

Comment: Thank you so much both answers worked in my case. This will sound like a rookie question but does the triple "<" just indicate that there will be three variables looking for input?

Comment: No, `<<<` specifies a here-string, basically a shortcut for a one-line here-document. It's unrelated to the number of variables you expect `read` to set.

Comment: @CyberStems: no, read more about here strings here: [here strings](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/x17837.html)